# Using jquery to get the height of one div and change margin on another

Tags: jquery, css

I have a php while loop that reads data from a db.
In that while loop is a div of variable height, and another div.
I am trying to get the height of the first div and apply that number to the top margin of the second div as a minus:margin-top: -first div height.
I am using this code

```
<script>
var height = $(".artistinfo").height();
$(".artistimage").css("margin-top", - height);
</script>
```

This code is working but it is getting the height for the first div in the first db record and applying it to the margin of the second div in ALL records.

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Edit:

This is the html in my while loop

```
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $data )) { 
$img = $info['image'];
$image = substr($img, 3); 
echo "<div class='artistdiv'>";
echo "<div class='artistinfo'>";
echo "<div class='artistinfotext'>";
echo "<div class='heading2'>";
echo $info['artist'];
echo "</div>";
echo nl2br($info['info']);
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='artistimage'>";
echo "<img class='resizedimage' src='$image' />";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";}}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code that you're trying to change the attributes of.

Comment: Question edited with the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the CSS with the *css* method and a callback that traverses to the closest previous *artistimage*, gets its height and returns it to the method as the value to be set.

```
$( ".artistimage" ).css( "margin-top", function() {
  return $(this).prev('.artistinfo').height() * -1
});
```

Comment: This works, but now .artistinfo overflows artistdiv into the next artistdiv element

Comment: Thats because you asked to set a negative margin, just remove the *-1 then.

Comment: Thats not it. The solution done what i wanted, it set a neg margin on artistimage. But now if artist info is higer than artistimage it overflows the container!

Comment: I guess thats an issue with the question then, not with the answer to it ;)

Comment: I guess your right, accepting this answer as it did what i asked! Thanks